# How to use Č Ž and Š in java

Tags: java, utf-8

So i have this code:

```
public class Java{

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Scanner vh=new Scanner(System.in);
    String niz=vh.nextLine();
    char pod_niz=vh.next().charAt(0);
    int a=(int)pod_niz;
    System.out.println(a);
        int index=niz.indexOf(pod_niz);

           if(pod_niz=='č'){
                String m=niz.replace(niz.charAt(index),'c');
                System.out.println(m);
           }

            if(pod_niz=='š'){
                String m=niz.replace(niz.charAt(index),'s');
                System.out.println(m);

           }

             if(pod_niz=='Ž'){
                 String m=niz.replace(niz.charAt(index),'z');
                System.out.println(m);

           }

}
}
```

But java does not recognize č,š,ž.
How do I enable them?

Comment: What's this language ?

Comment: this is slovenian but the letters are also used in serbian,bosnian,czech,...

Comment: I suggest you make sure that the console is using the correct character encoding.  You could also use a debugger to check what characters are really being returned by `vh.next()`.  I wouldn't be surprised if they're something completely different from what you are expecting.

Comment: It also looks like your code sample has a capital `Ž`, but lower case `č` and `š`.

Comment: maybe, this was a stupid program anyway i have found a better way

Answer (score 0):

Try with unicode

```
č  - \u010d
š  - \u0161
ž  - \u017e
```

as,

```
if(pod_niz=='\u010d'){
```

Comment: Rakesh, this isn't going to work.  The compiler will just replace the Unicode escape sequences with the characters.